# Uploading Lua code to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I have Arduino UNO board. Can I upload programs written in Lua?
I wrote a code for simple home automation using relays to control lights and tried to upload it to my Arduino board, I get error code of "Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno"? What does this mean?

This is the code I used:

```lua
var("Switch", "ME.BI21")
var("Relay", "ME.BO21")
var("RelayState", "ME.BO41")

RelayState = 1

Relay = Switch

if (Relay == 1 then){
  print("The Relay is ON")
}
else{
  print("The Relay is OFF")
}
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The Uno can’t run Lua code. The ESP8266 modules like the Wemos D1 or NodeMCU can, with the right firmware.